# Deploy Python Desktop Application to Web

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, bots

folks.

I'm completely new to Pyhton development and i want to know some basic things.
I need to make a bot that access an API and want it to keep running on a server. I did some search and found Google App Engine + python as the best solution for this. So, i have a code example but its a "desktop" app. 
I want it to be running on a server (Google App Engine or something like it), every X minutes and when i access the web adress of it, i would like to see the log on screen (just for monitoring).

Here's the code example (of course i don't need the input things and so. It would be hard coded variables in the application. And i know the "print" method wont work as well):
[GitHub Code](https://github.com/betfair/API-NG-sample-code/blob/master/python/ApiNgDemoJsonRpc.py)

Coud you guys help me?

Comment: Hey high_depression... do you have a specific problem at some point doing your app?  The app engine provides a ton of tutorials you can look at. If you have a specific issue with one of them we'll be happy to help... but here you're basically asking us to design the application for you...

Answer (score 0):

Start here for App Engine intro: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Then see GAE Cron docs here to "do something every X minutes": https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

If you have any specific questions / problems once you start porting your app - come back and post them. I glanced over your code quickly and don't think you should run into any issues although don't expect anyone here to do your job for you.